# many issues with syncing iTunes from 10.15.3 Catalina to iPhone 7 iOS 13.3

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

so I moved my iTunes from iMac to a MacBook Pro Catalina 10.15.3 using Migration assistant.  Ive always had 1 library, "William's stuff".  Now it seems that I have a library called My Library and William's stuff.  Sometimes I get and option to select one or the other and sometimes there is no option.  See screenshots.  What is My Library and why do I get an option sometimes to select it and sometime not?  Ive talked to senior apple advisors with no luck - "they've never seen this before".  I can't even tell where they are located.....  Any help?

[image: library option screenshot]